# unable to install fedora16 KDE

Tags: windows-7, linux, installation, partitioning, fedora

I have already installed Win7 on my machine. There are 3 partitions that have been done. Now i want to install another OS which is fedora 16 on my laptop but not on the virtual machine. i.e I want to dual boot Win7 and fedora 16. When i start the installation after inserting DVD i reach a page :
[image]
and then select *Use free space* which is 20GB , but i get a message not enough space available. Why is this so ? How can i install fedora 16 KDE ?

*Partition Table:*
[image]

Comment: Could you show us your partition table?

Comment: @ Simon Sheehan add the table

Answer (score 0):

If I'm seeing it correctly, you have four primary partitions. System can not have more than four primary partitions, [more info here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#PC_partition_types). However, it is possible to have three primary paritions and one [extended](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Extended_partition) partition which can have more logical partitions.

tl;dr
Delete one of the primary partitions, create extended partition.

Comment: Extended/Logical

Comment: @SimonSheehan What do you mean? By creating extended partiton, fedora installer will create rest of the partitions automagicly.

Comment: Ah I see, never mind

Comment: who do you call a primary partition ? I mean to say what is a primary partition in layman

Comment: and how do you say i have 4 primary partitions ?